# Angular JS Social Sharing

Tags: angularjs, node.js, meta-tags

I have an angular website with these meta tags

`<meta property="og:type" content="{{type}}" />
 <meta property="og:title" ng-bind-template="{{title}}" />
 <meta property="og:description" name="{{description}}"/>`

Now the problem is that everytime the crawlers crawls into the page it shows the curly braces. The suggested answer for this issue https://github.com/michaelbromley/angular-social-demo was to create a PHP server side script. But the problem is the backend for the website is node js. Is there any way to create this solution to node js?

Comment: The server side language doesn't matter. You can generate the content with any language.

Comment: But sir the problem is that with the crawlers they render {{title}} instead of the set value for the title.

Comment: You said you had already found a solution to that problem in PHP. You wanted to know if you could use NodeJS instead of PHP. I told you you can. Why are you restating your original problem?